# laravel how to add a one to one relasionship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a `restaurant` table with `id` and `manualaddress_id` fields.

I have a `manualaddress` table with `id` and `restaurant_id` fields.

of course I have more fields but I am trying to simplify the problem.

Every restaurant has one manual address and each manual address belongs to one restaurant so the relationship is one to one.

#### First of all

Should I really add the `restaurant_id` to the `manualaddress` table?

#### Second

I know that to have this relationship in the model, I have to use this:

```
class ManualAddress  extends Eloquent{

    public function restaurant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Restaurant', 'id');
    }
```

and this:

```
class Restaurant extends Eloquent
public function manualAddress()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('ManualAddress', 'restaurant_id');
    }
```

but that makes me in a problem, which is:
I can't add a restaurant because each restaurant must have a `manualaddress_id` and I can't add an manual address because each manualaddress mush have a `restaurant_id`

I am right? I am confused :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the id.

```
return $this->belongsTo('Restaurant');
```

One advice: 
Table names always in PLURAL.  So not 'restaurant', but 'restaurants'.

```
public function restaurant()
{
    $this->belongsTo('Restaurant');

}
```

And then this for the many.

```
public function restaurants()
{
    $this->hasMany('Restaurant');

}
```

Please check the laravel docs and read it very carefully. Most stuff is explained in great detail. Also these questions have been asked many many times on Stack overflow.

Also, for questions like this, I'd like to invite you to the irc.freenode.net #laravel channel. To come and chat with us. We will help you there.

Comment: Thanks but I already read the documentation and I had a question. secondly, I told you that I need one to one, not one to many. why did you write `has many`? third, should I remove the `manualaddress_id` column from the `restaurant` table? or should I remove the `restaurant_id` column from the `ManualAddress` table?

Comment: To show you why you should change your table names. And NO you should not remove restaurant_id. Just think for a minute. How can restaurant find it's address when there is not reference to itselve?

Comment: by making a query on the maual address table where the restauran_id is something, right? I really didn't get you. the two columns should NOT be deleted right? plus, the doumentaiton states that I should use hasOne not hasMany for one to one relationship, why u choose hasMnay?